# BigQuery - Clustered tables not reducing query size with multiple keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to optimize my querying in BigQuery for cost, and I have been trying out Clustered tables.
For reference: [BigQuery - querying only a subset of keys in a table with key value schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594068/bigquery-querying-only-a-subset-of-keys-in-a-table-with-key-value-schema)

Clustering the table by a single column is successfully reducing my query size. However, using multiple columns (example shown in: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-clustered-tables#sample_table_used_in_the_examples) is not leading to any reduction in query size.

To use the example given in the documentation,

```
SELECT
  SUM(totalSale)
FROM
  mydataset.ClusteredSalesData
WHERE
  customer_id = 10000
  AND product_id LIKE 'gcp_analytics%'
```

This queries the entire data set (say, 100GB) if there was no clustering on the table, reduces to about 10GB (seen after actual run, not at the validator) when clustered only by customer_id, but does not change at all when clustered by both customer_id and product_id (even after actual run of the query).

I have tried changing the order of the clustering, order of the WHERE clauses, etc. Nothing seems to change anything.

Is this expected behavior? Bug on BigQuery? Or am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to @Pentium10 for pointing me to: https://medium.com/@hoffa/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b

To use the examples from the blogpost, among the following two queries,

Q1:

```
SELECT wiki, SUM(views) views
FROM fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2017
WHERE DATE(datehour) BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-30'
AND wiki = 'en'
--AND title = 'Barcelona'
GROUP BY wiki ORDER BY wiki
```

Q2:

```
SELECT wiki, SUM(views) views
FROM fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2017
WHERE DATE(datehour) BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-30'
AND wiki = 'en'
AND title = 'Barcelona'
GROUP BY wiki ORDER BY wiki
```

I would have expected Q2 to be cheaper since clustering is by (wiki, title), but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Data in all BigQuery tables are stored in chunks. For clustered tables, data is clustered so a chunk might only contain data for a single cluster. When clustered tables are scanned, only the matching clusters/chunks are charged. If filtering by customer_id already reduces to 1/10 of the chunks, filtering by product_id might not lead to less chunks. For example, if customer_id = 10000 already reduces to 1 chunk, filtering by product_id won't reduce the cost more.

Comment: Makes sense, this is how I understood clustering by a single column worked. But how does this work when table is clustered using multiple columns? In my mind, it would have to chunk it in combinations of the values of the primary and secondary columns specified, so adding secondary product_id filter would have to filter only a sub-subset of the chunks.

Comment: @error_magnet read this: https://medium.com/@hoffa/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b

Comment: @Pentium10 Thanks, hadn't seen this. Will update my question using this.

Comment: there is a typo in the article as well, that first and second query in your question should be on v3 as well, as only v3 is partitioned and clustered

Comment: Ah, you are right. Edited in my post.

Comment: Why do you say "but that does not seem to be the case."? In the similar example in Felipe Hoffa post data processed changes from 114GB to 3,83GB.

Comment: @RubénC. There is a small difference. I have commented out "title" filter, while Mr. Hoffa has commented out "wiki" filter. Since the table is clustered in (wiki, title) order, I understand that there is an increase in query size when "title" is filtered without "wiki". My question is, since filtering by "wiki" offers reduction in query size, does the secondary filter on "title" offer a further reduction? Doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: It depends on the size of the your data. BigQuery tries to maintain an optimal chunk size. If data for customer_id 10000 is less than the optimal chunk size,  all the data will reside in one chunk, and filtering by product_id won't help; if the data is bigger enough that it resides in two chunks, filtering by product_id can further reduce the cost from 2 to 1. Chunk 1: customer_id 10000, product_id "aaa" to "ppp". Chunk 2: customer_id 10000, product_id "qqq" to "zzz".

Answer (score 2):

In your Query 1 (Q1) - estimated cost is $0.43 for processing `86.1 GB` - actual bytes billed - `18.4 GB`

For Q2 - estimated cost $0.90 for processing `180 GB` - actual bytes billed - `10.3 GB`

Sounds like cheaper to me :o)

But in reality, save is even greater than just `down to 10.3 GB from 18.4 GB` - it is actually `down to 10.3 GB from 38.6 GB`. It is because in Q1 there is no `title` column involved at all, while in Q2 it is!
So, to compare apples to apples - you can add `title` as in below - you will see that estimated cost will be `180 GB` - while actual bytes billed - `38.6 GB`

Q3:

```
SELECT wiki, title, SUM(views) views
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2017`
WHERE DATE(datehour) BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-30'
AND wiki = 'en'
-- AND title = 'Barcelona'
GROUP BY wiki, title
```

Note/reminder: when you query clustered table - estimation is shown based on partition only (as of now - my understanding that later this will be fixed/improved)

Answer (score 2):

I tested the next queries based on [this post](https://medium.com/@hoffa/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b), suggested by [Pentium10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243782/pentium10):

```
SELECT wiki, SUM(views) views 
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2017` 
WHERE DATE(datehour) BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-30' 
AND wiki = 'en' 
AND title = 'Barcelona' 
GROUP BY wiki ORDER BY wiki
```

180.19GB processed (according to the `validator`). 10.3GB processed running the query.

```
SELECT wiki, SUM(views) views 
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2017` 
WHERE DATE(datehour) BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-30' 
AND wiki = 'en' 
--AND title = 'Barcelona' 
GROUP BY wiki ORDER BY wiki
```

86.1GB processed (according to the `validator`). 
18.4GB processed running the query.

```
SELECT wiki, SUM(views) views 
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2017` 
WHERE DATE(datehour) BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-30' 
-- AND wiki = 'en' 
AND title = 'Barcelona' 
GROUP BY wiki ORDER BY wiki
```

180.19GB processed (according to the `validator`). 
113.85GB processed running the query.

Everything looks coherent since, as Mr. Hoffa said, "order matters" for clustered tables ('wiki' saves more than 'title').

Is true that the validator is still not properly working but `clustered tables` are [still on beta](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables), so we can expect an improvement in the future.

Comment: One of the things with clustered tables, is that accurate cost estimates cannot be provided before running the query. We use information available at runtime to reduce cost and improve performance. We'll be trying to make this cost estimate tighter for clustered tables, but have many scenarios where that estimate will only be an upper bound.